# how to fix an element in bottom while the keyboard is open

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a page that has an element at the bottom of the page. I use position `absolute` to fix it to bottom. When I open the keyboard he element goes to middle of the page.

**It's a normal situation**
[image: 1]

**I want this**
[image: second image]

**And this is my problem**
[image: third image]

```css
.container{
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
}
.myclass{
    position : absolute;
    bottom:0;
    margin:auto;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
}
```

Comment: You forgot a semicolon in `myclass`

Comment: no i forget that in my code has semicolon.

Comment: look at the images

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mobile keyboard pushes up content because of an absolutely positioned drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43702979/mobile-keyboard-pushes-up-content-because-of-an-absolutely-positioned-drawer)

Comment: I think that it's something with iPhone, that when you type it happens. Because I tested it on a computer and it worked just fine

Comment: no i saw this question

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
display:flex;
flex-direction: column;
```

in your main container

and add your .box element `margin-top: auto;` will fix your problem i guess.

**Press the button**

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container');

const addButton = document.querySelector('button');


addButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.style.height = "10rem";
    newDiv.style.width = "100%";
    newDiv.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    container.appendChild(newDiv);
})
```

```css
*, 
*::before,
*::after{
    margin: 0;
}


body{
    min-height: 100vh;
}


.container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
    width:375px;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: bisque;
}

.box{
    height: 5rem;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    margin-top: auto;
}

button{
    position: absolute;
    width: 5rem;
    height: 5rem;
    top: 5rem;
    right: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <h1>Enter text</h1>
      <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<button>Add new box</button>
```